# Is there a quick way to manually rearrange methods in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, ide

I have recently switched from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I miss being able to rearrange the methods in a .java file by simply dragging and dropping them in the class structure window. Is there a way to do this or something similar in Android Studio? (Obviously I can cut and paste in the editor window, but I was hoping there might be a more efficient way.)

Comment: i believe you know about ctrl+alt+shift+L shortcut. It will rearange the variables but wont change methods order

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Move Statement Up/Down shortcuts to rearrange methods quickly. Put your caret on the method name and press Ctrl-Shift-Up/Down (Cmd-Shift-Up/Down on Mac OS X) to swap it with either the previous or next method.

Comment: Great, thanks. Not quite as quick as eclipse, but better than block copy and pasting :)

Comment: Is there any way how to automatize this method sortin as part of reformat code process in IDE?

Comment: On Mac, it's Cmd+Shift+Up/Down

Comment: I recommend collapsing all functions ( Ctrl + Shift + -   on Linux/Windows ) before moving - It would be much easier to identify the new structure.